# Extracting  matches  for a regular expression?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I like to see the  list of  matches for a regular expression  in a separate buffer without the surrounding text. For example I like to see all class names  defined in my HTML document. Additionally I like to see the counts for each matches.  Is there any emacs library for this?

For example if I have a text:

```
add related resources or links
always respect the original author"
```

and a regexp

```
"re."
```

I am looking for matches and count

```
rel: 1
res: 2
```

Please observe  that rel is from "related" and res is from "resources" and "respect"

Comment: Can you try to give an example of input and outputs you'd like?  If you reduce the amount of work readers have to do to parse and understand your question, they become more likely to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun my-re-counter (regexp)
  (interactive "sregexp: ")
  (let (matches)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
      (let ((match (assoc (match-string 0) matches)))
        (if match
            (setcdr match (1+ (cdr match)))
          (push (cons (match-string 0) 1) matches))))

    (pop-to-buffer "*regexp counts*")
    (erase-buffer)
    (dolist (match matches)
      (insert (car match) ": " (int-to-string (cdr match)) "\n"))
    (goto-char (point-min))))
```

Comment: Great, exactly as I asked.  This can be enhanced further. For example when you click on a particular match in the result, it will show them in M-x occur M-x highlight-regexp way in another buffer. Another suitable display would be  as tree-nodes as in M-x org-mode.